# How to remove old administrator from WSo2 EMM system

Tags: mobile, wso2, windows-server-2012, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-iot

I have launched a new WSo2 EMM system on windows server 2012. I added in a test administrator to try this out though now I would like to remove the test account.  I can remove any user I would like though I cant seem to remove an this admin account.

Any help would be great. Thank you

Comment: Probably this question should be moved to superuser. Out of moderator flags today :(

Comment: are you trying to delete admin user on carbon ?

Comment: Yes a test user on the Wso2 Emm mdm console

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can delete. You can login to the system and under the configuration menu you have the remove link to remove the user. Also additionally you can login to the admin console using

> `https://localhost:9443/admin/carbon/admin/index.jsp?loginStatus=true`

and there is a section called users and roles. There it lists the users. Remove it from their.